# Missing Bitcoin Transaction

Tags: lost-transactions

Earlier this month I requested 2 payouts from BTCGuild for .25 each.

[image: BTC Guild Payout Detail]

Neither one ever showed up in my wallet, and I just figured I messed up somehow and lost it.  But today I started sniffing around after requesting another payout (which I have received) and found this:

[image: Botcoin Info]

With the "Request Payment" button, is this still something I can retrieve?
And if so, how do I do it?
Thanks in advance for any and all info, good or bad.  Either way it will be a lesson learned.

Comment: I don't think scribbling out your address will do anything for your anonymity considering that theres a QR code, transaction timestamp, and that past used addresses can be searched for and found using only the last 4-7 characters.

Answer (score 3):

"Request Payment" is just a nifty little tool that generates a QR code that points to the address on the page, so it won't help you unless you want a QR code for the address.

Check to see if the address you've sent to is in a wallet you own. If you have lost the private keys to the address, the only thing you can do is try to find them. It's nearly impossible to regain control of addresses you've lost or forgotten.